# Getting Eclipse Indigo Startup Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash-reports, eclipse-indigo

I am learning Android development and the IDE I am using for this purpose is Eclipse Indigo. I had downloaded Android Toolkit as well.

The problem I am having is that: Every time I am trying to launch my eclipse indigo, I face the following error.

```
An error has occured.See the log file
C:\Users\sony\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_3_7.0_1089725520\configuration\1393276264055.log
```

Earlier I got the following error (which was resolved using eclipse clean
C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipse -clean" I guess):

```
An error has occurred. See the log file C:\Users\sony\workspace.metadata.log
```

Then i got platform error or something similar.

THIS IS THE LOG :

```
!SESSION 2014-02-25 00:07:05.837 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=tr_TR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-02-25 00:07:08.162
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Program Files\Android Eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.icu_4.4.2.v20110823.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.basicOpen(ZipBundleFile.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getZipFile(ZipBundleFile.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.checkedOpen(ZipBundleFile.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getEntry(ZipBundleFile.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseData.getEntry0(BaseData.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseData.getEntry(BaseData.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.AdaptorUtil.loadManifestFrom(AdaptorUtil.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseStorageHook.getGeneratedManifest0(EclipseStorageHook.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseStorageHook.getGeneratedManifest(EclipseStorageHook.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseStorageHook.createCachedManifest(EclipseStorageHook.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseStorageHook.getManifest(EclipseStorageHook.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.loadManifest(BaseStorage.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BundleInstall.begin(BundleInstall.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.installWorkerPrivileged(Framework.java:930)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework$1.run(Framework.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework$1.run(Framework.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.installWorker(Framework.java:897)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.installBundle(Framework.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.installBundles(ConfigApplier.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.ConfigApplier.install(ConfigApplier.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.SimpleConfiguratorImpl.applyConfiguration(SimpleConfiguratorImpl.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.simpleconfigurator.Activator.start(Activator.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:274)
    ... 41 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-25 00:07:11.878
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-25 00:07:11.878
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.launching_3.6.1.v20111006_r372.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.launching 2 0 2014-02-25 00:07:11.878
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.icu.text_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-02-25 00:07:11.879
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.101.r37_20110819.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.help.ui 2 0 2014-02-25 00:07:11.879
```

Comment: Can you paste the errors in the log file?

Comment: Can you also paste the output of 'echo %JAVA_HOME%'?

Comment: Can you enlighten us with your solution please?

Comment: i change indigo version to juno problem solved